# Find each matches in php

Tags: php

I want to find a particular matches of strings (want to find middle string by giving parameters start and end string ) from an HTML file i used the following code

```
 $string = " ".$ipt;
 $ini = strpos($string,$start);
 if ($ini == 0) return "";
 $ini += strlen($start);
 $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
 return substr($string,$ini,$len);
```

it can find the middle sting but it can only return 1 match from HTML file i want all possible matches PLEASE HELP ME

starting string is - `<div class="product">`
 end is - `<br class="no">`

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the same methods you used in the code above, take a look at this:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#108426

Other than that, there is preg_match:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php